# Loop through all checkboxes that are inside a div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to loop through all checkboxes that are inside a div tag with id #abc123

How can I do this?

```
$("#abc123").foreach( ???? )
```

**Update**
my html row looks like:

```
<tr>
<td><input .../> </td>
<td>234</td>

</tr>
```

I need to add the value of the `<td>` into the ID of the checkbox.

Would I just get the parent, then ancestor it somehow?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$("#abc123 input[type=checkbox]").each(function()
     {

     });
```

UPDATE:

Ok, Let'd see if I got this straight.  Given:

```
<tr> 
<td><input .../> </td> 
<td>234</td> 
</tr>
```

You want the result to be (effectively)

```
<tr> 
<td><input id="abc234" .../> </td> 
<td>234</td> 
</tr>

$("td input[type=checkbox]").each(function()
{
     var id = $(this).next("td").text();
     $(this).attr("id", "abc"+ id);
});
```

Comment: see my update, is it just .parent(). and then somehow I traverse tothe next element?

Answer (score 5):

```
$("#abc123 input[type=checkbox]").each(function() {
    $(this).dosomething();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `onkeydown` event... I recommend the tab key which is `keycode` "9"

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
  if(event.keyCode == '9'){ 
  ... 
}
```

Inside the `if statement` you'll need a `nested if statement` that checks which element is in focus and then assigns focus to the next element like this :

```
document.div.id.focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't label where `#abc123` is in your code. Also, do the `<td>` tags have any identification? The following may work.

```
$("#abc123 input:checkbox").each(function(i) {
    id = $(this).closest('td').next('td').text();
    $(this).attr('id', id);
});
```

I am not sure how deep your `<div id="abc123">` is in the `<td>` so I used the closest() method to get to the cell wrapper. If it is only 1 deep, i.e. there is no `<div>` as it appears in your code, then you can just use parent(). Good luck.